# How to open the application its settings with nativescript on both Android and IOS?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, settings

I would like to know how you can open the app settings page on both ios and android.

Answer (score 1):

Change `org.nativescript.app` with your app's package id.

```js
import { Application, isAndroid } from '@nativescript/core';

const openAppSetting = async () => {
  if(isAndroid) {
    var activity = Application.android.foregroundActivity || Application.android.startActivity

    activity.startActivity(new android.content.Intent(
      android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
      android.net.Uri.fromParts("package", "org.nativescript.app", '')
    ))
  } else {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication.openURL(NSURL.URLWithString(UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString));
  }
}

export {
  openAppSetting
}
```